# CSS Hover Effect Cut Off On Images Within Columns (Chrome only)

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, hover

I have put the content on my forum into three columns and attached a hover effect to the images within each post.  This hover effect is to enlarge the images and the CSS is:

```
.MessageList .Message img:hover {
-webkit-transform:scale(1.2);
-moz-transform:scale(1.2);
-ms-transform:scale(1.2);
-o-transform:scale(1.2);
transform:scale(1.2);
position: relative;
z-index: 1;
}
```

my testing website is: http://idenitties.com/

and I've created a jsfiddle to try and explain my issue: http://jsfiddle.net/eKJ9k/

**If you open the jsfiddle in Chrome - the hover effect is cut off**

**If you open the jsfiddle in Firefox - the hover effect works perfectly**

Does anyone know why the effect works in one browser and not in the other?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a webkit bug. Nothing you can do about it, except switch to using something else (flexbox?)

Possibly related to or the same bug as mentioned [here](http://www.barryvan.com.au/2009/10/css-columns/#bugs).

> Text that overflows the column horizontally is chopped off